# Typo3/Typoscript: indexed_search doesn't work with rootPidList

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to use indexed_search in Typo3 4.6 but I have problem.
My page has a few main trees and I only want to search in the current tree. 
The indexing works fine, seaching in all trees works too. But if I set the rootPidList to the id of my root page of the tree I want to search, then I got no results. :(
Any ideas?

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.search {
    rootPidList = 1234
    page_links = 10
}

plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
    templateFile = typo3/sysext/indexed_search/pi/indexed_search.tmpl
    _DEFAULT_PI_VARS.results = 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution that worked for me. If somebody else has the same problem, her my solution:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
    _DEFAULT_PI_VARS.sections=rl1_1234

  search {
      rootPidList = -1
  }

}
```

Restriction of the section 1234 which is my tree I want to search in